# xampp connection timed out after loading 3~40 seconds when access with external ip

Tags: apache, server, xampp, wamp

I have a serious problem that accesses with external IP to my home web server(xampp).

When I access with external IP to my xampp server
the browser loads 3~40 seconds and connection timed out error occurs.

I've searched for this problem for two days but there is no one has the same problem with me.

> I thought it is configuration problem but same error occurs even apache wasn't turned on.

Here is the detail of my problem. the browser loads 3~40 seconds and connection timed out error appears

1. access with localhost works properly
2. access in my computer with private IP works properly
3. access with private IP from another device that connected to the same network occurs error
4. access with external IP occurs error.
5. I'm using a home router and I configured port forwarding to my computer. (80 - 8000)
6. static IP was set up to 192.168.1.95. not dynamic
7. port 80 is allowed in firewall.
8. same error occurs even while apache server turned off.
   [browser pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i6Eu.png)

Comment: this looks like a firewall issue. Double check that you allow port 80 TCP not UDP. Try disabling your firewall temporarily(!!) and try accessing the server again.

Comment: ㄴ
oh... i've never had firewall problem. thanks for teach me! it works fine now!

Answer (score -1):

access with private IP from another device that connected to the same network occurs error
this one easy solve by change WordPress Address (URL) to same ip address of server
for example
normal it is
https://locallhost/example
change to
https://192.168.0.2/example